# PHP get "min, max, step and value" variables from plugin to quantity box Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the Woocommerce Advanced Quantity plugin which gives me the possibility to have a different min, max, increasing step quantity, and default quantity for each product. My new theme has the quantity box on the shop page and it is not getting the values from the plugin. It is set aways as default min: 1 step: 1 value: 1. I need to adapt the theme to always get these values from the plugin.
Anyone could help me with this?

[plugin code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Udqk.png)

[woocommerce.php from theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAc3c.png)

Code from plugin:

```
    <div class="plus-minus-button">
    <div class="quantity <?php echo !is_single($product_id) ? 'smaller-minus-plus' : ''; ?> <?php echo is_cart() ? 'on-cart-plus-minus-button' : ''; ?>">
        <input type='button' value='-' class='woo-advanced-minus'/>
        <input type="text" id="qty" class="plus-minus-input qty" step="<?php echo esc_attr($step); ?>"
               min="<?php echo esc_attr($min_value); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr($max_value); ?>"
               name="<?php echo esc_attr($input_name); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($input_value); ?>"
               title="<?php echo esc_attr_x('Quantity', 'woo-advanced-qty') ?>"
               <?php echo isset($step_intervals) ? 'data-step_intervals="' . esc_attr(json_encode($step_intervals)) . '"' : ''; ?>
               pattern="<?php echo esc_attr($pattern); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr($inputmode); ?>" data-product_id="<?php echo esc_attr($product_id); ?>"/>
        <input type='button' value='+' class='woo-advanced-plus'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code from woocommerce.php from theme:

```
            if(ot_get_option('groci_quantity_box') == 'on'){
            if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'groci-plus-minus'); 
            $output .= '<div class="plus-minus">';
            $output .= '<div class="cart-plus-minus">';
            $output .= '<div class="dec qtybutton">-</div>';
            
            $output .= '<input type="text" class="qty-archive" step="5" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">';
            
            $output .= '<div class="inc qtybutton">+</div>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        $output .= groci_add_to_cart_button();
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        
        
    }
    $output_escaped = $output;
    
    echo $output_escaped;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Woocommerce Advanced Quantity plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/advanced-product-quantity/) is a paid plugin so I'm unable to inspect its code. However, I assume it must be storing the min, max and other such values in the database in some way.

The code you shared from the plugin shows a mention of `$min_value` but it doesn't say how a value was assigned to it.

Most of the time, we fetch value from the WordPress database using [get_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) function.

Let's assume a min value was stored in the database with the option name `waq_min_value` then it would be fetched with `get_option()` as follows:

```
$min_value = get_option( 'waq_min_value' );
```

You would then be able to get and use it in your theme like this:

```
$min_value = get_option( 'waq_min_value' );

$output .= '<input type="text" class="qty-archive" step="5" min="'. $min_value .'" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">';
```

Again, this is under the assumption that a value was already [added](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) with the option name `waq_min_value`.

TLDR: The plugin must be storing the values in the database. Find out where it is stored, what name it is using. With that info, you can fetch the data and use it in your theme.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have found that this information is stored in wp_postmeta table. Inside that I have the following information for a value:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
--------------------------------------------------
| 902 | 72 | _advanced-qty-value | 789789 |


The value I have set for the Standard value was 789789.

Do you know how can I set in the code to get this value?

Thanks again!! :)

Comment: This is the pic of the results: https://pasteboard.co/K3I9dPY.png

Comment: I couldn't access the pasteboard link, it's returning a 504 error. Since the info you need is stored in `wp_postmeta` table, you should be able to retrieve it using [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function. Make sure to check example usage of this function both on WP.org and SO to understand it better.